# Lesti FPC is caching the minicart on header

Tags: cart, full-page-cache, mini-cart, memcached, caching

I managed to get Lesti FPC working with memcached, but I quickly ran into a problem.

 When I add an item to my cart from any page and go back to the homepage, it shows that my cart is empty.

 I understand that I need to specify the block names for cache exclusion in configuration page and I added the following on the module configuration:
[image]

[image]

My Site URL is https://www.yogastudio.co.uk and I believe that the cart-header block name is correct. 
 Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you check your layout .xml files for your theme? I think it should be `cart_header`

Comment: <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_header" template="checkout/cart/topcart.phtml"/>
I have this

Comment: I updated cart-header to cart_header. Now the icon on the cart is showing wrong numbers while the actual minicart shows correct cart items.

Comment: Interesting - take cart-header out of 'bypass' also, as its technically an invalid handle. Are there any embedded blocks in checkout/cart/topcart.phtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this to work,
Then I realized that this website has Amasti FPC plugin and I was able to find out the blocks for the cart icon and cart side bar.

The blocks were:

> cart_header,cart_icon

The site was using claue theme, if anyone else stumbled upon this issue again, I hope these two blocks will help you.